# actionbar tabs fragment layout to cover only part of screen

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

From an Android example I can see how to do
ActionBar tabs and how to use tabs for fragment switching, however in the example the fragment layout covers the whole screen.
I want to put some controls at the bottom of the screen,
 which should be a part of and controlled by activity itself.

So i want to keep the bottom of the screen same while clicking on tabs and switching between fragments.

Thanks

Comment: show us what you have done first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sunil said, you have to create the bottom layout in your MainActivity. So the layout will be something like below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:weight="9"/>

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:weight="1"
     android:text="Common BUtton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the FragmentTransaction pass R.id.fragment_holder as it will be container for fragments.

Comment: Surely, let me know how it goes. And you can appreciate Sunil's work and mine by accepting the answer or upvoting if you find it helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the screen using LinearLayouts into two sections. For example give one linear layout a weight of 9 (to occupy 90% of screen) and the other a weight of 1 (to occupy 10% of screen) - then put the fragments in the LinearLayout with weight 9. This way your fragments have their own container and you have another container at the bottom which your activity can use to do whatever it likes and it will be visible and accessible from all the fragments just like your tabs.

Comment: So i would do this here ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag); What would i pass instead of  android.R.id.content?